# generating completely random even numbers with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, random, numbers

is there any good method to generate **random even** numbers with C#? I came up with this code:

```
    Random RandString = new Random(0);
```

code:

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 50;

        int rand = RandString.Next(min, max-1);
        while (rand % 2 == 1) // odd
        {
            rand = RandString.Next(min, max-1);
        }

        textBox4.Text = "" + rand;
    }
```

Problems with this code:

- my current solution might not be the fastest of all
- very often, numbers that are generated by this method are repeated with the same sequence! For example after 5 iterations I can get: 8, 10, 20, 30, 16. After more clicking (for like 15 seconds) I can get 10, 30, 20  **in a row** or 30, 20, 10.. I'm not sure, but that's NOT what I call "random".

so is there any way to deal with the problem that I've described, or is there any other method?

Comment: Completely random? I don't think anyone knows how to produce provenly random sequences, only pseudo-random.

Comment: Random can be repeated. It's still random. By excluding previously seen values you're being decidedly *not* random.

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: Start with a perfectly good ordinary random number and multiply by two. Twice as random! :-)

Comment: it can be repeated! sure! but what's the probability that **the same three numbers** will be repeated after 15-20 numbers?? that's what I'm having! and it's not "random" - it's "repeating"

Comment: @Oded: Typical Linux installations can provide true randomness through '/dev/random', but the pool of entropy is limited - see my answer.

Comment: If you specify `0` as seed when you call the `Random` constructor, you will get the same sequence of "random" numbers every time. So don't use `new Random(0)`. Use `new Random()` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
textBox4.Text = (2 * rand.Next(min / 2, max / 2)).ToString();
```

Comment: your solutions is twice as fast after 100k of iterations! the only thing that's worth mentioning is that you don't need to subtract 1. For example to get a value in the interval [0-988] i need to set "min" to 0 and "max" to 1k. If you want to get [0-1000] then the "max" should be set to 1001.

Answer (score 2):

even easier would be to take your result and multiply it by 2

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 25;

    int rand = RandString.Next(min, max-1)*2;

    textBox4.Text = rand.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Random random = new Random();

int nextnum = random.Next(min/2,max/2) * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) to get a "more random" (which is a silly term I admit) number. There is a nice eample on MSDN's documentation page.

As others recommended, you can just multiply the result with 2 to get an even number.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of flaws in your approach.

First of all, `Random` from .NET isn't completely random in the cryptographic sense AFAIK, but it should be much much better than the results you report. Most likely, you are creating a new `Random` object on every iteration of your loop; since the current system time is used to seed the RNG, you will get the same sequences of pseudo-random numbers if you do runs very short after one another. Instead, create one instance of `Random` at startup, and keep it around for as long as possible.

Then, creating an even number from a random integer is much easier than looping until you find one that happens to be even: just generate one random number and clear the least significant bit: `myRand.Next(min, max-1) & ~1;`. A decent RNG has a uniform distribution over all of its bits, so clearing any bit shouldn't reduce entropy by more than, well, one bit.

Getting back to the 'completely random' part: `Random` provides a pseudo-random number generator. It is seeded once, based on a value that is somewhat random-ish (the least-significant parts of the current system time), but given the same seed, the RNG will reliably and deterministically produce the same numbers on every run. If you want true randomness (a.k.a. 'entropy'), you'd be surprised how hard it is to produce it on a machine that was built for deterministic calculations. UNIX and Unix-like systems typically offer a pool of entropy through a special kernel-generated file (`/dev/random`), using things like hard disk access timing, network noise, and whatever other sources of actual randomness they can find, and distillate those into a uniform distribution using fairly complicated calculations. Windows can probably do the same, but I am unaware of any API for this in either .NET or the classic win32 API.